# Stop a service while Windows is updateing

Tags: c#, .net

sorry if this has been already answered here, I couldn't find it, I did not look for it more then 20 minutes I admit, but my college said it cant be done.

Our software runs two services while running, during a Windows update however, they can run in to problems as Windows stops it services or do things during an update.

I wonder if there is a way to detect if windows update is in progress/being downloaded etc (admin access granted) to use it so the services can act accordingly. Is it true that there is no such feature in windows right now?

Pointing me to the direction of where to dig is appreciated as well!

Thank you for your time and help!
(developing .NET using xaml, c#, rest, zeroMQ)

Comment: "as Windows stops it services" - not clear, are you referring to windows stopping your services or windows stopping OS services that you are dependent upon? If the latter, are the services you require actually listed as service dependencies?

Comment: latter and not necessarily, I saw "crash" of our service with one of our internal module timeing out, our with one where REST could not connect to SQL (that one actually didnt cause a crash cause its handled ). I'm sure we could go around and fix every possible hole, but it would be better to just see somehow if a windows update process is running in the background and if so act accordingly. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of detecting if a specific process (e.g. windows update) is running you're better of detecting and handling the Stop command that is sent to your service by the Service Control Manager. Implement an [OnStop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop?view=netframework-4.7.2) handler in you service (or any other appropriate handler like OnShutdown) and execute your required actions from there.This is a more generic approach and will help in all situations where your service is stopped. If really needed you can always detect in your OnStop handler if the windows update process is running at that time.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds promising

Comment: I looked it up and as far as I can tell, we receive no Stop order from the SMC during windows update, should we? I need to log that. Also update can cause problems with other services (SQL for example) that in turn can cause problems on our side, most of these are handled, but vital ones can still cause a crash. Thats why I was looking for a way to detect win update as my first approach